# Output to fetch in single row

Tags: python

Example:

```py
Reporter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/issuetable-web-component/table/tbody/tr[" + p + "]/td[5]/span/a").get_attribute('rel')

s = Reporter
```

Output:

```
user1
user2
```

Expected:

```
user1,user2
```

Comment: Yes am using selenium with python, the output i am getting for the value s "should be like (user1,user2)"

Comment: The first output is a list or str?

Comment: @SyedAsimHashmi first output is string

Comment: It would be great if show us the html element which you are trying to select.

Comment: Please clarify your question. See [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

You could try to format that output:

```
your_string = """
user1
user2
"""
```

If you need it as a tuple like your comment:

```
new_tuple = tuple(your_string.strip().splitlines())
```

Or as a string:

```
",".join([str(x) for x in your_string.strip().splitlines()])
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering your loop is filling Reporter which is a list of Strings

```
    Reporter = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/section/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/issuetable-web-component/table/tbody/tr[" + p + "]/td[5]/span/a").get_attribute('rel')


   // joins elements of Reporter by ',' and stores in sting s 
    s = ","
    s = s.join(Reporter)
```

Comment: Getting output as  
u,s,e,r,1
u,s,e,r,2

Expected is user1, user2

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try the following and check -

```
s = s.replace('\n', ',')
```